# Is it accurate to describe a computer as a dynamic memory state?

Tags: it.information-theory

is this an accurate statement? And where can I find out more about these topics?

> At any point in time a computer is *holding* a memory state. Because
> the computer is moving in various ways we can call it a dynamic memory
> state. It is the purpose of computers to transform memory states.
>
> Modern computers have an advantage over much older devices like an
> Abacus in that an operator can not only input instructions and initial
> data, but also the device itself can continue running on its own
> calculations (calculations that were unknown to the operator).